# How to make a task wait on WCF async callback function?

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, task-parallel-library

I have WCF async begin end pattern to call a service function. I have the begin function wrapped inside a task. When task is awaited, it does not wait for the callback function to finish that is passed to the begin function. How can I make it wait for the callback function to finish executing? Thank you.

Here is what I have.

```
Public Sub Process(pCase)        
    Dim client As CaseRecord.CaseRecordPort
    client = New CaseRecord.CaseRecordPortClient
    DirectCast(client, CaseRecord.CaseRecordPortClient).Open()

    Dim clientTask As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
    client.BeginCaseProcess(pCase, AddressOf CaseRequestCompleted, client)
                                                End Sub)

    clientTask.Wait()

     If IsPaid() Then

     End If
End Sub

Private Sub CaseRequestCompleted(ByVal result As IAsyncResult)
    Dim client As CaseRecord.CaseRecordPortClient = DirectCast(result.AsyncState, CaseRecord.CaseRecordPortClient)
    Dim tCaseResponse As CaseResponse = Nothing
    Dim sError As String = ""

    Try
        tCaseResponse = client.EndCaseProcess(result)
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
       sError = "Timeout error"
    Catch ex As Exception
       sError = ex.Message
    Finally
        RaiseEvent CaseRequestCompleted(tCaseResponse, sError)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2013+ (I think 2012 as well) can generate proxies tha use *Tasks* instead of Begin/End methods. Perhaps the easiest solution would be to rebuild the proxy to generate Task-based methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StartNew` is a dangerous API and should not be used. In your case, you don't even need it anyway.

Instead, of calling `Begin*`/`End*` explicitly, you can use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to wrap them up. My VB is rusty, but the C# code would look like:

```
CaseResponse tCaseResponse = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginCaseProcess,
    clientEndCaseProcess, pCase, null);
```

For more information, see [TAP wrappers for APM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#ApmToTap).

Comment: Perhaps an easier solution would be to recreate the WCF proxy. VS 2013+ (at least) generate task-based proxies

Comment: Currently, the project was set to .net framework 4.0. Is it possible to recreate the WCF proxy to generate task based operations with .net framework 4.0? Thank you.

Comment: @Jyina: No; to do it automatically, it must target 4.5.